# Build NGINX with module?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to build NGINX with a custom module.

I clone the [module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) I want to use.

I then clone [NGINX](https://github.com/nginx/nginx).

I change directory into the `nginx/auto`, where I try to run the configure script with:

```
sudo ./configure --add-module=/home/philip/projects/nginx-rtmp-module
```

I get back the error:

```
./configure: 10: .: Can't open auto/options
```

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I was able to get this working by downloading the tar file rather than using the git repo:

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.5.3
sudo ./configure --add-module=/home/philip/projects/nginx-rtmp-module
```

Answer (score 2):

If the source code is cloned from github, you should use `./auto/configure` in the root directory instead of `./configure` in auto directory.

Comment: Btw, the OP has solved their problem. And, this is a 3 year old question... Nice job on research 

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana This post comes first in google search, hopefully this simple trick will help others.

Answer (score 0):

*** EDIT ***
Just saw you can run ./configure with a prefix argument, I haven't tried this after I fixed it, but you can probably

```
$: ./configure --prefix=/path/to/nginx
```

---

The configure script is using a relative path that isn't resolving correctly. Not sure why this is the case, but this is how you can correct it.

This is how I did it:

1. Find the Nginx configure script by searching for the auto/options file

```
$: find / | grep auto/options
/build/src/nginx/nginx-1.15.11/auto/options
$: ls /build/src/nginx/nginx-1.15.11 | grep configure
/build/src/nginx/nginx-1.15.11/configure
```

2. Take a look inside the configure file, look for auto/options. Replace it with the absolute path.

```
. /full/path/to/nginx/auto/options
```

3. When you try to configure now, it will throw a new error - you need to replace every relative path. Make sure you are in the directory with the configure script, so that when you `ls` you see the configure script, then run this code to search and replace each `conf` script with the absolute path.

```
find ./ -type f | grep "conf" | xargs sed -i 's/. auto\//. \/build\/src\/nginx\/nginx\-1\.15\.11\//g'
```

In the example above, I used the absolute path for *my NGINX* you need to replace it with the path to yours, the directory that contains the 'configure' file